# mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002) Конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение

Tags: xampp

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Всем доброго времени суток! Вопрос: я пытаюсь настроить Dolibarr. Скачано, установлено, но есть проблема: в конце покаzываетъ ошибку mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002) Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение in D:\xampp\htdocs\dolibarr\htdocs\core\db\mysqli.class.php on line 218. Можете подскаzать где ошибка? Благодарю

Answer (score 0):

Трудность преодолелъ, просто при установке надо оставить порты Apache и MySQL 80 и 3306, как они устанавливаются по умолчанію, а когда появится сообщеніе "Port 80/3306 already use..", во всплывающем окне нажать "Нет"[image: введите сюда описание изображения]